# why my c program doesn't crash when i entered the wrong data type

Tags: c

I'm new to c and I'm writing a basic program that ask the user for input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float weight;
    printf("enter your weight in kg:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%f", &weight);
    printf("your weight is %f kg\n", weight);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works as expected when I under a number when asked for input. But when I accidentally entered words, the program doesn't crash and instead print out `your weight is 0.00000 kg`.

I was just wondering, why doesn't my program crash when it expect numbers but I have entered words? and why did it printed out `0.00000`?

Comment: did you tried removing fflush(stdout)?

Comment: [A good `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might be handy. Pay close attention to what the function *returns*.

Comment: @Stargateur I have found information on `scanf()` function at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Input-Functions.html

Comment: Why did you expect it to *crash*, specifically? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @KevinRED I put `fflush(stdout)` in there because without it, eclipse will ask me for input first without printing out the first line

Comment: `scanf("%f", &weight);` failed.  The value of `weight` is not specified.  The result of subsequent code is not defined.  You code is unlucky to report 0.000000

Comment: @Thor Your use of `fflush(stdout)` is valid. Don't worry.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the reference. I was just wondering, is this the reference you mostly use when program in c? Is there any other references you would recommend?

Comment: @AnT I have some experience in java, and java program seem to crash even when little things goes wrong lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why my c program doesn't crash when i entered the wrong data type

When a user of your program enters some input that can't be converted by `scanf` to a float, the variable `weight` will not be initialized. So when the program prints the variable, it will read an uninitialized float. According to the c standard, that has undefined behavior.

However, undefined behavior does **not** guarantee a program crash. It may crash or it may continue execution. We can't know as it is undefined what will happen. On your system execution just continued but on another system a program may happen.

On many systems the memory allocated to a program as startup is initialized to all zeros. Therefore variables in `main` is (often) an all zero binary pattern when left uninitialized. For floats that translate to the value `0.0`

So even if you don't initialize `weight` it seems as if it was initialized to zero and your program runs fine even with input like `abc` and prints the weight as `0.0`

**However, from a standard point of view it is still undefined behavior to read an uninitialized float variable**

If you did the same inside a function that you called a number of times (with other function calls in between), you would see strange behavior sooner or later.
Typically just a print of strange values but on some systems, you might see a crash (but that is more rare).

You should do:

```
if (scanf("%f", &weight) == 1)
    printf("your weight is %f kg\n", weight);
else
    printf("Illegal input\n");
```

Comment: Useless and not important Note: "However, from a standard point of view it is still undefined behavior to read an uninitialized variable", only for type that have trap representation. If not the value is just unknown but this is not undefined behavior. Yes, I lose my time by reading the standard. However, I don't know if float has trap representation.

Comment: Thanks @chux and 4296427 for the answer!

Comment: @Stargateur As I recall the standard the only variable type that you are allowed to read when it is uninitialized is `unsigned char` as it is guaranteed not to have any trap representation. I should have mention that. I'll update the answer to work around that. Thanks.

Comment: @Stargateur oh wow, that is pro as! one day, i want to be like you, one day lol :P

Comment: well actually @Stargateur cut some corners here. It is undefined behaviour to read an uninitialized variable of automatic storage duration whose address is never taken, period. ---- However, the address of `weight` was taken, so it must have been placed in memory, so its value is now indeterminate. ---- While the use of indeterminate values is allowed provided that they're not trap representations, the view of the committee is that the use of such values as arguments to standard library functions, such as `printf`, again have undefined behaviour, so ...

Comment: And to ping @Thor as well

Answer (score 2):

Every input the user gives in C is treated as a string, though the input you provide is in numbers. After getting the input from the user, it is converted in to numeric data using atoi (ascii to integer) function ([man atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)). The return value of this function is the converted value. Upon successfully converting the given string to an integer it returns the converted integer value and it returns zero when the resultant value is a non-integer. This is the reason why it is not showing any error when you input different data.

Try the same code with different format specifiers, so that you can have a clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The [MAN page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `scanf` :

> **Return Value**
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

So, `scanf` return the number of arguments successfully scanned. that's why your program not crashing.

Answer (score 1):

the program does not crash because the input does nothing to cause a crash.

However, the posted code does have a major flaw.  This line:

```
scanf("%f", &weight);
```

should be:

```
if( 1 != scanf("%f", &weight) )
{
    perror( "scanf failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, scanf successful
```

In other words, always check system functions for errors, especially those that are performing input.